Is creating a ton of date objects bad? Is there a more performant way to do this?
I have a method in one of the shared utility class. It just logs an event when called:
public static newEvent(message: string): void {
    const t_option = {
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        fractionalSecondDigits: '3',
        hour12: false,
    } as Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions;

    const now = new Date().toLocaleTimeString([], t_option);        
    const formattedMessage = `[${now}] ${message}`;
    
    this.eventService.publish(formattedMessage);
    console.log(formattedMessage);
}

This sort of logs something like this to console (and saves in a file log somewhere else):
[15:01:13.929] initialising...
[15:01:50.588] connecting to websockets...
[15:02:06.384] websockets connected (3)
[15:04:02.992] fetching weather data...

This log method is being called from pretty much all the services and components in the angular application. There are a LOT of calls. Maybe around 10-12 a second on a busy day.
My issue here is that I'm creating a new Date() for each message logged. I want the timestamp to be in a human readable format, but I am wondering if creating a new date object is the best way to do it?
If I create one static date outsuide the method then the timestamp is not live, as in, every time the date/time will be the same as when it was created. If use Date.now() instead, I get unix timestamp, but, it's not human readable.
So my question I guess is, is there a better way to do what I want without creating a ton of new object? Or is this trivial enough that I don't have to worry about it?

What's the problem with new Date when what you want is, well, a new date?

@deceze - my question is whether creating a new date object 10 times a second is a good idea. Question is about performance, not about alternates

Do you have any indication that creating 10 date objects a second is any sort of performance bottleneck? JS is an object oriented language, you'd expect object construction wouldn't be some expensive special case to avoid…

What's your metric? How do I measure if it's a good idea or not?

Are you asking if it is a good idea or are you asking if it is better/worse performance than something else?  Because the first is off-topic for this site, and the second is up to you to measure.

Well, new Date() is slightly slower than Date.now(), at least according to my testing on this benchmarking site. So with dozens of calls per second, it could become an issue.
It's especially much slower when you add .toLocaleTimeString(), as seen here, and even worst when adding options.
But really, without testing it, it's hard to say if it will have a measurable impact.
For optimal perfs, I'd suggest printing a Unix timestamp in your logs when your software is running, and then using a log reader that can parse it into readable dates

Thank you, at least you understood my question and attempted to answer, even if my question was vague. The benchmarking site was pretty helpful for me to understand the performance difference.... No wonder stackoverflow is vanishing into obscurity, the people here are quick to dismiss and too strongly opinionated. They're no longer helpful like they used to be.

@LocustHorde The benchmark shows a minuscule difference on my browser, and still 35m ops/sec either way. It is entirely pointless worrying about a dozen ops/s in this case. That’s what makes this question rather close worthy.

The benchmark shows a minuscule difference on my browser, and still 35m ops/sec either way. It is entirely pointless worrying about a dozen ops/s in this case @deceze - this exact thing was what I wanted to know, thanks!
